# Draw Simple Horizontal Line On GL Surface View

Tags: android, view, line, surface

Good day. I am pretty much frustrated as what I want to achieve is the simplest thing in world but nowhere I could get anything. I just want to draw an simple HORIZONTAL line in the centre of the GL surface view (the idea is to make audio wave animation based on the amplitude of the recording) so I did achieve that simply and easy with canvas, but with GL surface view there are not even one simple example or one simple question on how to exactly draw that line on the surface of gl.

Anyway here is what I got and have no clue where I should write the draw code and what should I write to achieve above desired function.

GL Render class

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    GL10 unused;

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        // Redraw background color
//        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        this.unused = unused;

    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

}
```

GL View class (this class is copy pasted from another one which extends SurfaceView so do not take a notice of the canvas and etc.They will be deleted)

```
public class GLView extends GLSurfaceView {

    // The number of buffer frames to keep around (for a nice fade-out visualization).
    private static final int HISTORY_SIZE = 1;
    private MyGLRenderer mRenderer;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    private boolean isFinished=true;
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int colorDelta = 255 / (HISTORY_SIZE + 1);
            int brightness = colorDelta;
            final Random rnd = new Random();
            mPaint.setColor(Color.argb(brightness, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256)));
            isFinished = true;
            brightness += colorDelta;
        }
    };
    // To make quieter sounds still show up well on the display, we use +/- 8192 as the amplitude
    // that reaches the top/bottom of the view instead of +/- 32767. Any samples that have
    // magnitude higher than this limit will simply be clipped during drawing.
    private static final float MAX_AMPLITUDE_TO_DRAW = 10000.0f;

    // The queue that will hold historical audio data.
    private final LinkedList<short[]> mAudioData;

    private final Paint mPaint;

    public GLView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mAudioData = new LinkedList<short[]>();

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer();

        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }

    public GLView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mAudioData = new LinkedList<short[]>();

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer();

        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }


    /**
     * Updates the waveform view with a new "frame" of samples and renders it. The new frame gets
     * added to the front of the rendering queue, pushing the previous frames back, causing them to
     * be faded out visually.
     *
     * @param buffer the most recent buffer of audio samples
     */
    public synchronized void updateAudioData(short[] buffer) {
        short[] newBuffer;

        // We want to keep a small amount of history in the view to provide a nice fading effect.
        // We use a linked list that we treat as a queue for this.
        if (mAudioData.size() == HISTORY_SIZE) {
            newBuffer = mAudioData.removeFirst();
            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, buffer.length);
        } else {
            newBuffer = buffer.clone();
        }

        mAudioData.addLast(newBuffer);

        final Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
        if (canvas != null) {
            drawWaveform(canvas);
            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Repaints the view's surface.
     *
     * @param canvas the {@link Canvas} object on which to draw
     */
    private void drawWaveform(Canvas canvas) {
        // Clear the screen each time because SurfaceView won't do this for us.
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        float width = getWidth();
        float height = getHeight();
        float centerY = height / 2;

        // We draw the history from oldest to newest so that the older audio data is further back
        // and darker than the most recent data.
        int colorDelta = 255 / (HISTORY_SIZE + 1);
        int brightness = colorDelta;
        final Random rnd = new Random();
        if(isFinished){
            isFinished = false;
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
        }
        for (short[] buffer : mAudioData) {

//            mPaint.setColor(Color.argb(brightness, 128, 255, 192));

            float lastX = -1;
            float lastY = -1;

            // For efficiency, we don't draw all of the samples in the buffer, but only the ones
            // that align with pixel boundaries.
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int index = (int) ((x / width) * buffer.length);
                short sample = buffer[index];
                float y = (sample / MAX_AMPLITUDE_TO_DRAW) * centerY + centerY;

                if (lastX != -1) {
                    canvas.drawLine(lastX, lastY, x, y, mPaint);
                }

                lastX = x;
                lastY = y;
            }

            brightness += colorDelta;
        }
    }
}
```

Please...can you help me and tell me how to draw horizontal centered line on this gl surface view?

Comment: Why would you use a `GLSurfaceView` if you're not using GL for drawing?

Comment: i mentioned that you do not need to take a notice of the glsurfaceview code,thats is the part where i am asking for help on GL line drawing